# making the main Thread sleeps

Tags: multithreading, android, thread-sleep

I'm designing an android app that requires me to make the `main Thread` sleeps for a certain amount of time, I know that this will make the app freeze and the **UI** will be not an editable material, BUT, that's what I need in my app and I'm fine with that, the problem is, when the user **consequently** hitting the **UI** while the `main Thread` is sleeping, the app crashes and gives me the following `Log`:

```
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542): ANR in com.example.myapp (com.example.myapp/.Login)
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542): PID: 1339
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.)
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542): Load: 0.67 / 0.36 / 0.14
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542): CPU usage from 8638ms to 2834ms ago:
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   2.7% 112/mediaserver: 0.1% user + 2.5% kernel
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   1.2% 542/system_server: 0.6% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 10 minor
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   1% 100/vinput: 0% user + 1% kernel
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   1% 1339/com.example.myapp: 0.8% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 19 minor
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   0.5% 102/local_opengl: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   0.3% 109/surfaceflinger: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   0.1% 56/adbd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   0% 103/local_gps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   0.1% 598/com.android.systemui: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   0% 697/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542): 4% TOTAL: 1.4% user + 2.5% kernel
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542): CPU usage from 696ms to 1199ms later:
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542):   1.7% 100/vinput: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
06-15 13:10:57.620: E/ActivityManager(542): 2% TOTAL: 2% user + 0% kernel
```

How can I preventing making my app ignore any user interactions while sleeping?

if it's worth to mention, I'm catching the `InterruptedException` while making the `Thread` sleeping:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Could you give more explanation why do you need to sleep main thread?

Comment: You can disable UI elements with good explanaiton to user and do not block main thread

Comment: Whatever you are trying to solve this way can be better solved by some other means.

Comment: @EugenMartynov I want the app to wait for a certain amount of time, to see if some processing gives it the desired results withing that time or it requires more time. and also I don't want the user to make any interactions with the app within that time.

Comment: So you can show progress indicator with explanation "Processing..." and disable UI for required duration

Comment: @CommonsWare I explained in the previous comment why I'm doing that, If you can provide me with a better way according to my needs, kindly refer to it

Comment: @EugenMartynov i thinked about that but I don't want to give the user that kind of message in the stage of my app. for sure this way is considered but as a plan B

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat please realise SO is online platform so people don't see comments and answers at the same time

Comment: Its not a good idea to put main thread to sleep. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/6092143/254567 . If still you wanna do that, you may try disabling the touch event on your activity before putting it to sleep. Check this out- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10721034/254567

Comment: "I don't want to give the user that kind of message in the stage of my app" -- you would prefer to frustrate the users, because they try using your app and it does not respond to user input, with no explanation of why?

Comment: @PushkarPandey I tried the way to disable the touch event without success.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have a please wait.. text view, i just don't want to raise dialogs in that stage of the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `setEnabled(false)` on the relevant widgets and action bar items to prevent them from accepting user input. Then, run your long-running work in the background, such as via an `AsyncTask`. Call `setEnabled(true)` on the relevant widgets and action bar items when the work is done, such as in `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`.

Note that you will need to deal with configuration changes, so that you re-disable the widgets and action bar items if the user rotates the screen while your background work is going on.

Also, please only disable the widgets and action bar items that are truly relevant to your background task. Do not block the user from navigating elsewhere in your app to places that do not depend upon this work (help screen, about screen, etc.).

You also may be better served using a `ProgressBar` instead of, or in addition to, your "please wait.. text view".